# comparing vectors in a large data set

Tags: c++, vector, comparison, large-data

I have a two dimensional vector of integer type that contains a large amount of vectors ( i.e `18000` and above ), and there is a considerable amount amount of repetitive vectors in this pool. What I want to do is to detect the similar vectors and delete one of them. 
What I am currently doing is that I am comparing each vector against the entire pool using the following function :`

```
bool compareVectors(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    return (a == b);
}
```

But this doesn't efficiently do the process presumably due to the large amounts of comparisons I am making. Is there any possible efficient ways to do this ?

Comment: When sizes differ, you do a useless copy.

Comment: Cannot you sort once each vector first ? then sort the vector of vector and run `std::unique` on that.

Comment: you can do size check in the main itself. you  do need to copy to that the function if they are equal.

Comment: You really don't care about the order of the elements to determine that two vectors are "equal"?

Comment: Also, if performance is the issue, passing the vectors by value may be undesirable.  Passing them by reference and making local sorted copies would be more efficient, since if sizes are different you avoid all the copying in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preparations:

1. First sort your vectors into buckets according to size.
2. Buckets with only one vector means the vector is unique, output and remove.
3. sort all remaining vectors in the remaining buckets

start with i = 0

Recursive Algorithm:

for each bucket:

1. sort vectors into buckets according to v.(i)
2. Buckets with only one vector means the vector is unique, output and remove
3. recurse into each bucket with i=i+1

Answer (score 0):

Build a `set` or `unordered_set` out of the canonicalized (here, sorted) versions of your (sub)vectors.  Then you can find all the duplicates in *O*(*mn* log *m* log *n*) time, where *m* and *n* are the outer and inner dimensions of your data respectively.

You might want a mapping instead to, say, store the index of the first representative of each equivalence class.  You can use [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/reserve) to remove the log *m* from the `unordered_set` running time.